# python Selenium find_element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, findelement

I had a problem using the Selenium library.
I don't know how to use find_element. And I get an error

[image: The button I want to press]

my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time,selenium

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"./driver/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://cin.guru/g/438694")
driver.maximize_window()
button = driver.find_element(By.class_name,"rounded-md mr-1 text-white font-bold text-base cursor-pointer py-1 px-3 mx-1")
time.sleep(5)
button.click()
```

but i get this error:

> button = driver.find_element(By.class_name,"rounded-md mr-1 text-white font-bold text-base cursor-pointer py-1 px-3 mx-1")
> NameError: name 'By' is not defined

I would be grateful if someone could help me

Comment: The `class` attribute in the DOM is a space-separated **list** of classes. You need to use only one of those in the `By.class_name` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this import statement

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```